# AWS Cloudformation list parameter for array type fails

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm creating a cloudfront distro with cloudformation and trying to use parameters to populate the aliases.

If I use a single string, it fails because it wants a list. And if I use a list, it fails because it wants an array.

For example, this works (no params):

```
<!-- language: json -->

{
    "Resources": {
        "FrontEndBucket": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "Properties": {
                "BucketName":"test.tester.huh"
            }
        },
        "CloudFrontDistro": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
            "Properties": {
                "DistributionConfig": {
                    "Aliases": ["testalias.tester.huh"],
                    "Enabled":true,
                    "Origins": [
                        {
                            "DomainName": "test.tester.huh.s3.amazonaws.com",
                            "Id":"OriginId",
                            "S3OriginConfig": { }
                        }
                    ],
                    "DefaultCacheBehavior": {
                        "TargetOriginId": "OriginId",
                        "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "allow-all",
                        "ForwardedValues": {
                            "QueryString": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when  I run this:

```
{
    "Parameters" : {
        "DomainAliases" : {
            "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "CloudFrontDistro": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
            "Properties": {
                "DistributionConfig": {
                    "Aliases": {"ref":"DomainAliases"},
                    "Enabled":true,
                    "Origins": [
                        {
                            "DomainName": "test.tester.huh.s3.amazonaws.com",
                            "Id":"OriginId",
                            "S3OriginConfig": { }
                        }
                    ],
                    "DefaultCacheBehavior": {
                        "TargetOriginId": "OriginId",
                        "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "allow-all",
                        "ForwardedValues": {
                            "QueryString": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It fails with this:
(*note: it does pass initial validation)

```
Property validation failure: [Value of property {/DistributionConfig/Aliases} does not match type {Array}]
```

Comment: NVM. Needed "Ref" instead of "ref". Egads.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the bare minimum requirements for AWS::CloudFront::Distribution and the sample from their page, the following template validated perfectly fine for me:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Parameters": {
        "DomainAliases": {
            "Type": "CommaDelimitedList"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "myDistribution": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
            "Properties": {
                "DistributionConfig": {
                    "Aliases": {
                        "ref": "DomainAliases"
                    },
                    "Origins": [{
                        "DomainName": "mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com",
                        "Id": "myS3Origin",
                        "S3OriginConfig": {
                            "OriginAccessIdentity": "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/E127EXAMPLE51Z"
                        }
                    }],
                    "Enabled": "true",
                    "DefaultCacheBehavior": {
                        "AllowedMethods": ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"],
                        "TargetOriginId": "myS3Origin",
                        "ForwardedValues": {
                            "QueryString": "false",
                            "Cookies": {
                                "Forward": "none"
                            }
                        },
                        "TrustedSigners": ["1234567890EX", "1234567891EX"],
                        "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "allow-all"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, when I do that I get: Property validation failure: [Value of property {/DistributionConfig/Aliases/0} does not match type {String}]

Comment: hey Joe- appreciate your help. please see edits above. initial validation passes, but actual creation fails...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself.  It wants Aliases in an array, not a string.  Added some square brackets and that fixed it:

```
"Properties": {
                 "DistributionConfig": 
                       {
                              "Aliases": 
                                 [
                                    {
                                       "ref":"DomainAliases"
                                    }
                                 ],
                       }
                 }
```